# JQUERY: (selector).load(url id), loads every second click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to not reload the page every click of a sub-gallery.

So I decided to .load the content in to the wrapper div of the page.

The content works and does change on first click without a refresh, but the second click does a reload and so on alternately..

I'm guessing the script doesn't know about the new content?

I used Jquery's .bind on the click event, the click event always fires without a page refresh. I tested this by commenting out the .load line and using a alert("wonga!");

It's the .load that causes the page refresh on the second click, not sure why though.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice about this, I will be most grateful.

```
$('#gallery_subgalleries a').bind('click', function() {
      $('.content_loader').load("index.cfm?subgallery_id=" + $(this).attr('rel') + "&gallery_id=" + $(this).attr('gallery_id') + " " + ".content_loader");
return false;
});
```

The script executes at the bottom of the page:

```
 <div class="content_loader">
     <!--- page content --->
     <div id="gallery_subgalleries">
          <a href=""  gallery_id="" rel="">sub gallery name</a>
     </div>
     <!--- page content --->
 </div>

 <script>is here</script>
```

I am unable to show the page source at this time..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you have more $('#gallery_subgalleries a') elements after the first page reload?

Comment: There is one instance of "<div id="gallery_subgalleries">" and after that I use ColdFusion to loop over and create the sub-navigation list.

This selector would be replaced by the .load on the first click with itself, that's why I used a bind.. that selector seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bring in new content, the new link element it contains *won't* fire the `load()` call. The reason for this is that the new link element didn't exist when you did the original `bind()`.

There are two ways around this.

You can either rebind the new links everytime you do a load i.e. rerun the snippet you have above.

The other better way is to use [event delegation](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery), which uses another element to listen for the clicks and doesn't require any rebinding. It's also super neat, you would only have to make one change to your code:

```
$('#gallery_subgalleries a').live('click', function() {
    $('.content_loader').load("index.cfm?subgallery_id=" + $(this).attr('rel') + "&gallery_id=" + $(this).attr('gallery_id') + " " + ".content_loader");
    return false;
});
```

Note the change from `bind` to `live`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer + explanation, this works perfectly now... I really appreciate when people here take the time to explain the reason. Thanks again!